# Mysql - avoid duplicate values

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT track,data FROM tracks WHERE id != ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT %d,%d"
```

and this are my values:
(always twelve values:)

**1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2**

Now I have two "double" values, 1 and 2.
How can I avoid that my ORDER BY RAND() is getting 2x the 1 or the 2?
Is this even possible?

EDIT:
Is DISTINCT working, when I select more than two columns and just the "track" is the same and "data" always something else?

On a quick check, DISTINC gave 2x -> 1 or 2.

Comment: what about `distinct track`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT track FROM ...
```

EDIT:

If you want to select two columns and display only one row per value in the first column, you'll have to [aggregate values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). For example by displaying the biggest value of `data` :

```
SELECT track, MAX(data) FROM tracks WHERE id != ?
GROUP BY track
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT %d,%d
```

Comment: does it work too if you SELECT track,data FROM ... means if you select two values but just the name is the same?

Comment: No it doesn't. If you `SELECT track, data...` how is SQL supposed to choose which data to display if you have to identical tracks ? Use Aggregation functions instead. See edit.